# How might I share a message URL that renders a preview the same way Slack does?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'd like to include Slack message URLs in a post message (using blocks, if at all possible) in such a way that it's rendered the same way Slack would render the message URL; "Posted in #channel | Dec 11th | View message", etc.

I've tried using the Block Builder Kit to test this out. Slack will render this URL as plain text (which I guess is obvious), but `verbatim: false` isn't an option for `plain_text`. My options seem limited and I'm wondering if maybe I'm overlooking an alternative way to do this?

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "https://mycompany.com/archives/C0H0DMAEB/p1576068001171300"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of what I mean showing Block Builder vs. URL paste: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy9YC.jpg

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am no sure I fully understand what you are asking. Do you want your links to render as clickable links instead of the full URL?

Comment: Are you looking to unfurl the message or ?

Comment: It might be considered unfurling, but I'm honestly not sure even after reading through the documentation. When you paste a Slack message URL into a Slack conversation it renders the message preview along with some additional context. I'd like to leverage that functionality; sending message URLs and having them rendered exactly the same way, but I've been unable to reproduce the effect using the Block Builder Kit. It simply sends the URL across in plain text or linked text in markdown. Hopefully that's a bit clearer.

Comment: Change the text type from `plain_text` to `mrkdown` that should render the text as a link

Comment: @CalebNjiiri What you're suggesting does render it as a link, but only as a link. I'm looking for it to be rendered as the message itself (or rather the variant that Slack displays). Including a link to exactly what I mean with Block Builder vs. simply pasting the URL into Slack: https://imgur.com/a/ThIuxrk

Comment: @David I have provided a solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need then is to avoid using blocks since text based links don't unfurl automatically. You need to pass the `"unfurl_links": true` in the `chat.postMessage` so if you are using Python's slackclient as in my case it would be as follows

```
response = client.chat_postMessage(
  channel=channel_id,
  text='<https://mycompany.com/archives/C0H0DMAEB/p1576068001171300>',
  unfurl_links = True,

)
assert response["ok"]
```

You can also dictate to slack how to behave when it encounters links in messages find more details [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling#classic_unfurling)

Comment: I think this was the answer I was looking for. I was hoping to take advantage of Block Builder features, but maybe not so this time around.

Comment: One thing to note also is that unfurling will work only for "public" channels (the ones without the padlock icon next to their names).